# Angular under Webpack can't find an existing file app.module.ts

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have my *webpack.config.js* like this.

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  entry: "./source/application/main.ts",
  output: {
    path: "./distribution",
    filename: "app.bundle.js"
  },
  module: { loaders: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" }] },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: "./source/index.html" })],
  resolve: ["", ".js", ".ts"]
}
```

It finds and interprets the file *main.ts* properly, except when bootstraping the module (third line below), it says that the file can't be resolved. This is my *main.ts* file.

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

The file that it can't resolve is there. If I change its name or remove it, my IDE tells that it's missing. However, for some reason, when bootstraping the process, the computer can't find it.

> ERROR in ./application/main.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./app.module in C:...\main
>    @ ./application/main.ts 3:19-42
>   webpack: bundle is now VALID.

The contents of the *app.module.ts* and *main.ts* were brought [from Angular.IO page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html).

I've seen some posts saying that it's because *config.json* not being valid and/or possibly some confusion on paths in Windows. However, I've verified that the file is valid and I've tried adding `context:require("path").resolve(__dirname, "app"),` to my Webpack config. It only resulted in not finding even the former file *app.ts*, so I disregarded that approach.

I've spend a number of days trying to make it work and I'm out of ammo. How can I even troubleshoot it?

Comment: this `import { AppModule } from "./app.module";` is implying that the files for `app.module` are in the **same directory** as the `main.ts`, which appears to be `./source/application/main.ts`.  is this the case?  also, a path resolve to `./app` wouldn't help here, since nothing is requesting anything from an `app` directory.

Comment: @Claies That is the case. All the three files (*main.ts*, *app.module.ts* and *app.component.ts*) are in the same directory. Also, I've tried to resolve using *./source/application* too but to no avail (not sure what *context: ...resolve()* does, though, so it was just me trying anything imaginable). I'm going to bounty this question because it drives me insane and I can't be the only one.

Comment: As everything looks correct to me, do you have a ``` tsconfig.json``` file at a right place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have invalid file extension configuration in your `webpack.config.js` - instead of

```
resolve: ["", ".js", ".ts"]
```

you should have

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".js", ".ts"]
}
```

**Edit:**

If you need to target **webpack2**,in your case the migration would be pretty painless - its only needed to remove `""` from extensions:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts"]
}
```